# SDK for creating Push Notification for Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

newbie here. I was doing some research on using Xamarin Forms for Push Notification. Understand there are APN (Apple Push Notification), FCM(Google) and WNS (Microsoft). However, I could not understand the iOS App rule on using Push Notification:

```
1)  Push Notifications
   https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/2016-06-13/

 1.1)  Apps that provide Push Notifications without using the Apple Push Notification (APN) API will be rejected
 1.2)  Apps that use the APN service without obtaining a Push Application ID from Apple will be rejected

    what if I use FCM ?


 2) What is the SDK for Xamarin forms to build a push notification app which will doing the registration and interacting with app back-end?
```

What is the best approach for Xamarin Forms?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apple Push Notification Service or **(APNS)** is the only one who can send push notifications to an iOS device. This is why we provision our app with the proper certificate.

The same applies to FCM or WNS. However, services like Amazon Simple Notification Service (AWS SNS), wrap around all three providers and allow us to make one simple API call to recieve notifications from all 3 providers.

For example, we then provide our certificate that Apple provides us to authorize SNS to send a notification to APNS on our behalf. Push notifications are usually device/platform specific.

AWS SNS Xamarin SDK documentation has good pointers : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/sns.html

This is a Xamarin.Forms Github [example](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/tree/master/XamarinSamples/SNS/SNSPushNotification) for the AWS SNS service.